# Getting find_package to find a different version of Lua

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, lua

I'm on Windows, with Visual Studio 2019, and I have the following CMakeLists.txt file:

```
project (demo C)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

find_package(Lua 5.2 REQUIRED)

add_executable(demo main.c)
target_link_libraries(demo ${LUA_LIBRARIES})
target_include_directories(demo PRIVATE ${LUA_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

This won't build because CMake doesn't find my version 5.2 of Lua. The machine I'm on has 5.1.4 installed through the old (deprecated) luaforwindows installer in C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1, and when I specify 5.1 (or no version at all) in the find_package() line, those are found.

There is no such installer for Lua 5.2 or later, so I downloaded the 5.2 binaries from https://sourceforge.net/projects/luabinaries/ and copied them to a similar directory structure under C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.2, but they aren't found. There is probably some environment variable or other way to give hints to the FindLua.cmake script - what exactly is the canonical way for this, on Windows?

What I've tried: I thought this was handled with CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH, so I added this to CMakeSettings.json:

```
      "cmakeCommandArgs": "-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=C:/Program Files (x86)/Lua/5.2",
```

but it had no effect. Still getting the old message:

```
1> [CMake]   Could NOT find Lua (missing: LUA_INCLUDE_DIR) (Required is at least version
1> [CMake]   "5.2")
```

Comment: "Binaries" are useful when you want to run a program which is **already built**. But for build(compile) the program you need the headers too. In case of Lua it is `lua.h` header which is needed. As you can see, among 4 files provided by your "binaries" there is no such file.

Comment: I know this. There is a second zip file with binaries for the Lua library and with the headers, which were installed in the right place (but turns out, had the wrong names).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out eventually. The library had to be called lua52.lib (the zip file I downloaded called it liblua52.a, and while I had renamed it to .lib, I had not used that name, causing FindLua.cmake to miss it). Then I also changed all my PATH, LUA_PATH, LUA_DEV and other environment variables to point at the 5.2 directory, and now it works. I wonder why CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH didn't work, though, because I want to be able to select a location per project.

Comment: I needed to add quotes around the path, since it contains spaces! That did it. -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.2"